# HTACCESS works in localhost but not in remote host

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I know this has been asking many times, but none of the solutions I tried worked.
All this works fine in my localhost. But after I uploaded on a remote host all controller links need the  "index.php/" pre-appended to them in order for them to work.

htaccsess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

the .htaccess file is in the CI root folder.

my config:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/";
$config['index_page'] = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

I already tried changing the  uri_protocol to "REQUEST_URI" and "ORIG_PATH_INFO", still no joy.
 I heard that there's a step involving setting up the httpd.conf  file and changing the "AllowOverride " to "ALL". But I guess I have no access to the httpd.conf in the remote server(shared).

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how exactly a shared host works, but it should be a way to change the apache configuration of your virtualhost

Comment: Or perhaps you need to add `RewriteBase /` to your .htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Works for me on local as well as on remote ..

Comment: Thanks m8 you're a life saver. How I love SO. You guys rock! :p